# Matplotlib imshow with ListedColormap showing wrong colors on boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to display some results of an image segmentation model I've built. To do so, I'm using a `ListedColormap`, `BoundaryNorm` and the `imshow` function. My mask is containing only integers from `[0, 4]` as a numpy array. But the edges between different segments contain random colors. In the following example, I'm converting the ground truth mask to this format, show that it only contains the values `0` and `3` with `np.unique` and plotting it, but the image contains more than just the colors mapped to the background and third class:

```py
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""
colormap:
background - black
defect_1 - blue
defect_2 - yellow
defect_3 - red
defect_4 - cyan
"""
cmap = ListedColormap(['k','b','y','r','c'])
bounds=[i for i in range(6)]
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# convert image from shape (1,h,w,num_classes) to (1,h,w) with coding like in cmap
_, _gt = test_datagen[3]
_ov = defect_overlay(_gt)
np.unique(_ov) # output is array([0, 3], dtype=int64)

# shape after np.squeeze(...) is (h,w)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
ax.imshow(np.squeeze(_ov,axis=0), cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

This is the image that is plotted:
[image: Bad plot]

As you can see, while the array I'm plotting only contains the third defect (mapped to color red) the outlines of the pixels containing color 3 are displayed in yellow and/or blue instead while those values are not present in the image I'm plotting. I've tried changing the `BoundaryNorm` to `[i-.1 for i in range(6)]` which didn't help. I'm using matplotlib version `3.4.2` and the shape of the images themselves (and therefore the masks im plotting) is `256x800` pixels.

Any tips on how to fix this would be appreciated.

edit: I forgot to meantion the colors showing on the boundaries depend on the colormap, i.e. when changing some of the colors, the boundary pixels also change color.

Comment: You probably want `imshow(..., interpolation='nearest')` to avoid antialiasing.

Comment: Yes, that works. It seems like the default interpolation method is `"antialiasing"` while the default value is `None` and I assumed `None` would yield the same results as `"none"`.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This will have a slightly better option in 3.5 to antialias after the color mapping.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18782